# How to make an if statement if a player makes contact with an object C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, if-statement, collision

I am new to unity and C#, and I am starting to grasp the concept of `if` statements. But I haven't been able to figure out an if statement for when the character makes contact with the enemy.

```
if (???)
{
   // the event statement will be here
}
```

Comment: Please read [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is the OnCollisionEnter event.

To use this event you need to add a collider to the player and the enemy.

You can now add this code snippet to your players script and modify it to your needs:

```
//Detect collisions between the GameObjects with Colliders attached
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{
    //Check for a match with the specified name on any GameObject that collides with your GameObject
    if (collision.gameObject.name == "MyGameObjectName")
    {
        //If the GameObject's name matches the one you suggest, output this message in the console
        Debug.Log("Do something here");
    }

    //Check for a match with the specific tag on any GameObject that collides with your GameObject
    if (collision.gameObject.tag == "MyGameObjectTag")
    {
        //If the GameObject has the same tag as specified, output this message in the console
        Debug.Log("Do something else here");
    }
}
```

If you don't want to check if the name matches then you could use tags instead.

source:
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collision-gameObject.html